# Uploading shapefile with more than 1,000 features to ArcGIS Online?

Tags: shapefile, arcgis-online

I have many GIS files that I was using to create some maps for my work. Our desktop version of ArcGIS expired and we decided to move to the basic online version. I am unable to upload any of my databases and all the shapefiles that I have are said to have over 1,000 features.

Is there any way I can get this to upload? Maybe splitting the data in two parts and uploading them separately?

Comment: This is not an answer to your question, but have you considered using an Open Source software rather than ArcGIS?  The reason I ask is because even if you move to AGOL, you may find there is still limited functionality.  Also, unless you want to play with credits like you're in an arcade, you may want to look at other products.  One that comes to mind would be Quantum GIS.

Comment: I have thought about that but my work seems to be set on ArcGIS since that's the software we used to start with.

Comment: I understand completely - we are also a major user of ArcGIS.  However, I was pleasantly surprised with the capabilities of QGIS when I started looking into it.  You can add shapefiles and even connect to File Geodatabases.  It's easy to edit data and make maps.  Quite similar to ArcGIS in fact.  Like I said, I know my suggestion does not answer your question.  Ironically though I was in a discussion with a colleague on the very same topic yesterday so the thoughts were fresh in my mind.  If anything, try QGIS out and if you don't like it, then at least you know it's not for you.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds like it would be a lot easier to upload our data. I will run this by my boss again. Do you know if there is a limit to the amount of features a shape file can have?

Comment: Shapefiles cannot exceed 2GB or ~70 million point features.  AGOL sets a limit of 1,000 on shapefiles and csv's.  To publish more, you need an ArcGIS for Organizations account.

Comment: Have you tried "splitting the data in two parts and uploading them separately"?  I would expect that to work.